Не запускается Next.js
Делал все как обычно. Сначала npx create-next-app@latest, затем просто npm run dev. Ничего не менял в файлах, это просто самый обычный проект, но вот я запустил и вылезала такая непонятная ошибка. Помогите решить 

Наглядно же написано, ошибка возникла в next/font
Скорее всего не может достучаться до Гугл шрифта, попробуйте отрубить next/font или использовать localFont из этого пакета

уже решил проблему, откатил версию до 14.1.0. проблема была не в шрифтах, конечно я пробовал их удалять, вылезали другие ошибки, проблема оказалась в версии Next
